# Using kineticjs in ruby-on-rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, kineticjs

I'm trying to integrate a tool that I have developed in JS using kineticjs in a ruby on rails application. But I'm facing with a problem. Where should I put the kineticjs framework?
At the moment I have done this:

[image]

But I'm always getting this:

[image]

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Kinetic is not defined`

How should I include the kineticjs framework?

**Edit:**

Application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

drawingcanvas.js refers to kineticjs:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 0,
  y: PALETTE_HEIGHT,
  ...
```

I use the container id of a canvas element to do this:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: CANVAS_WIDTH,
  height: CANVAS_HEIGHT
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking some guesses:

- Am assuming that you are using the default `//= require_tree .` as the last line in `application.js`.
- Your `drawingcanvas.js` refers to `kineticjs`.
- somehow the default or your setting requires an element with `id='container'` to be present in the DOM.

Looks to me like there are multiple issues, if the above are correct.

The `require_tree` loads the javascripts in an order, and `drawingcanvas.js` is loaded before the dependencies are loaded. You also need to setup the dependencies for Kineticjs, example set the right container that it can bind to.

To avoid the order of loading affect the dependency, you can wait for the `document.onload` event, or `$(document).ready` if you are using jquery and then do the bindings.

**EDIT 1:**

[Here](http://runnable.com/VBWxnVm7evhfVjQp/ruby-on-rails-with-kineticjs) is an example inn Rails that I put together, based on the html example on KineticJs website.

Things to look at:

1. `routes.rb` - The root is mapped to `Home` controller, `Index` action.
2. `home.js` - This is where the javascript logic to generate the Tango example goes.
3. `home.html.erb` - Include page specific javascript block, to include reference to kinetic.js.

See it in action by running it.

Comment: Thanks @SrikanthVenugopalan! Yes your guesses are right! I have made an edit with more details.
How do I choose the order for the loads? And about the kineticjs dependencies how can I do it? This must be simple but I started learning ruby on rails some days ago, and I'm still learning.